Unable to Export Data In Hindi (Unicode) Excel using PHP and MySqli
Unable to Export Data In Hindi (Unicode) Excel using PHP and MySqli
Below is the code im using to export data from the database & its working fine but when i try to export hindi entries excel displays data like this à¤¸à¥à¤§à¤¾à¤‚à¤¶à¥ à¤•à¥à¤®à¤¾à¤° à¤ªà¤¾à¤‚à¤¡à¥‡à¤¯
also php form and database accepting hindi data, i'm facing problem while excel exporting only..glad if someone can help me regarding....thank you!
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
$date=date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '');
/* change character set to utf8 */
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'UTF8');

// headers for exporting excel
header("content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=student_data($date).xls");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: public");


function dataFilter(&$str_val)
{
    $str_val = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str_val);
    $str_val = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str_val);
    if(strstr($str_val, '"')) $str_val = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str_val) . '"';
}

$post_list = array();

//get rows query
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_data_demo"); //ORDER BY id DESC

//number of rows
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

//$id = 1;
if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $post_list[] = array( /**"id"=>$id**/ "id"=>$row["id"], "branch_id"=>$row["branch_id"], "admission_no"=>$row["admission_no"], "name"=>$row["name"], "fname"=>$row["fname"],  "mname"=>$row["mname"], "mobile"=>$row["mobile"], "dob"=>$row["dob"],  "address"=>$row["address"], "class"=>$row["class"], "section"=>$row["section"], "category"=>$row["category"], "gender"=>$row["gender"],  "student_image"=>$row["student_image"],  "status"=>$row["status"],  "adding_date_time"=>$row["adding_date_time"],  "field_1"=>$row["field_1"],  "field_2"=>$row["field_2"],  "field_3"=>$row["field_3"],  "field_4"=>$row["field_4"],  "field_5"=>$row["field_5"],  "field_6"=>$row["field_6"],  "field_7"=>$row["field_7"],  "field_8"=>$row["field_8"],  "field_9"=>$row["field_9"],  "field_10"=>$row["field_10"],  "field_11"=>$row["field_11"],  "field_12"=>$row["field_12"], "field_13"=>$row["field_13"],  "field_14"=>$row["field_14"],  "field_15"=>$row["field_15"] );
        //$id++;
    }
}


$title_flag = false;
foreach($post_list as $post) {
    if(!$title_flag) {
        // Showing column names 
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($post)) . "\n";
        $title_flag = true;
    }
    // data filtering
    array_walk($post, 'dataFilter');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($post)) . "\n";

}



See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored
